# invalidate nstimer in objective-c iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer, invalidation

I am having issue with invalidating a `NSTimer`.
I initialize a `NSTimer` with below function.

```
-(void) initLTTimer{
    [self shutLTTimer];
    [self setQuestion:questionCounter];
    isQuestionAttempt=NO;
    tmLeftTime=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateLeftTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSLog(@"Timer Initialized");
}
```

further I called a function `updateLeftTime` in its selector.

```
- (void)updateLeftTime:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    NSLog(@"%d",timeCounter);
    timeCounter+=1;
    tfLeftTime.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (QUESTION_TIME_LIMIT-timeCounter)];
    if (timeCounter>=QUESTION_TIME_LIMIT) {
        if (isQuestionAttempt==NO) {
            [self increaseDropShots];
        }
        [self setQuestionBg];
        timeCounter=0;
        [self shutLTTimer];
        [self updateQuestion:nil];
    }

}
```

This function `[self increaseDropShots];` called in above function.
here is the code of this function

```
-(void)increaseDropShots
{
    NSString *imgName = @"DactiveRetake";
    if (IS_IPAD) {
        imgName = [imgName stringByAppendingString:@"_ipad"];
    }
    wrongAttemp+=1;
    for (int i =1; i<=wrongAttemp; i++ ) 
    {
        UIImageView *img=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i+50];
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]];
    }
    NSLog(@"Question dropped counter: %d",wrongAttemp);
    if (wrongAttemp == 3)
    {
        [self shutLTTimer];
        [CommonFunctions initGlobalVars];
        [Bgplayer stop];
        [Bgplayer release];

        OverPageViewController *opvc=[[OverPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[CommonFunctions getXIBFile:@"OverPageViewController"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:opvc animated:YES];
        [opvc release];

    }

}
```

In this function I am killing this timer but I am unable.

```
   -(void) shutLTTimer{
    if ([tmLeftTime isValid]) {
        [tmLeftTime invalidate];
        tmLeftTime=nil;
    }
```

}
This is the whole scenario of my application

Please help me what is the issue.

Comment: 'I am unable'... unable to what?
Put a breakpoint at that point in your code and ensure it is getting called.

Comment: Oh1 thanks Actually I want to invalidate timer in "-(void)increaseDropShots" this function.

As you can check I have called shutLTTimer function in this function

is that make sense

Comment: I'm sorry, you don't seem to have understood what I asked you to do. Does the code definitely get to the line, `[tmLeftTime invalidate];`? You can check this by using a breakpoint or an `NSLog`

Comment: Thanks James! there was a problem in my code.

I was initiating the timer function by mistake.

invalidate function was called properly. but there was another issue.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer then.

Comment: I caught it.

its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answered after conversation in comments**

Does the code definitely get to the line, `[tmLeftTime invalidate];`? You can check this by using a breakpoint or an `NSLog`.